# Multiplying 3D matrix with 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices to multiply. One is the weight matrix `W`, whose size is **900x2x2**. Another is input matrix `I`, whose size is **2x2**.

I want to perform a summation over `c = WI` which will be a **900x1** matrix, but when I perform the operation it multiplies them and gives me a **900x2x2** matrix again.

Question #2 (related): So I made both of them 2D and multiplied `900x4 * 4x1`, but that gives me an error saying:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (900,4) (4,1)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how you will get a 900x1 from a 900x2x2 and a 2x2. Am I missing something? Which one is `W` and which one is `I`? What is the domain of application (this might help)?

Comment: Its the summation of 2x2 * 2x2 for 900 weights. Just edited. You would have understood it better if you would have implemented  ANN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to lose the last two axes of the first array against the only two axes of the second weight array with that matrix-multiplication. We could translate that idea into NumPy code with [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and assuming `arr1` and `arr2` as the input arrays respectively, like so -

```
np.tensordot(arr1,arr2,axes=([1,2],[0,1]))
```

Another simpler way to put into NumPy code would be with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
np.einsum('ijk,jk',arr1,arr2)
```

Comment: Okey ! But in general if we multiply `MxN * NxK` It should give `MxK` right. But numpy by default seems to give dot product when I tried to multiply `MxN * 1xN`. So technically there is nothing wrong in Q2) still it gives an error . why ?

Comment: @Hima Well in NumPy when working with NumPy arrays, `*` means elementwise multiplication and `np.dot/np.tensordot` is used to perform matrix-muiltiplication, if that clarifies it?